# Ajustar foto ao fazer upload

Tags: php

Colegas.

Tenho um sistema onde criei um método de upload:

```
public function gerarThumb($foto){
   $diretorioNormal = "../../produtos/";
   $novaLargura = 997;
   $novaAltura = 665;
   $miniatura = imagecreatetruecolor($novaLargura, $novaAltura);
   $imagem = imagecreatefromjpeg($foto);
   imagecopyresampled($miniatura, $imagem, 0, 0, 0, 0, $novaLargura,   $novaAltura, $largura, $altura);
   imagejpeg($miniatura,$diretorioNormal.$foto,90);
   return $foto;
} // Fim do método gerarThumb
```

Até aqui tudo bem, tudo certo, porém se uma pessoa não tirar a foto horizontal, ela fica esticada. Um exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de saber se tem como ajustar as fotos, independente se a foto é horizontal ou vertical, mas mantendo todas com a mesma altura e largura, mesmo que crie bordas brancas ao lado no caso da imagem ser vertical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, você deve redimensionar a imagem sem distorce-la. Você não pode usar largura ou altura fixas como está fazendo nas linhas 3 e 4.

Comece recuperando a largura e altura da imagem com a função [getimagesize()](http://php.net/getimagesize), exemplo:

```
$imgInfo = getimagesize($pathImg);
$larg = $imgInfo[0];
$alt = $imgInfo[1];
```

Depois você deve verificar qual é maior, se é a altura ou a largura, e a que for menor você recalcula proporcionalmente (para não distorcer).